# file upload not working after updating jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file-upload

I've searched everything but my error stays.
Following scripts is my code:

```
var client = null;

function fileChange()
{
var fileList = document.getElementById("fileA").files;
var file = fileList[0];

if(!file)
    return;

document.getElementById("progress").value = 0;
document.getElementById("prozent").innerHTML = "0%";
}


function uploadFile()
{

var file = document.getElementById("fileA").files[0];

var formData = new FormData();

client = new XMLHttpRequest();

var prog = document.getElementById("progress");

if(!file)
    return;

prog.value = 0;
prog.max = 100;


formData.append("datei", file);

client.onerror = function(e) {
    alert("onError");
};

client.onload = function(e) {
    document.getElementById("prozent").innerHTML = "100%";
    prog.value = prog.max;
};

client.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
    var p = Math.round(100 / e.total * e.loaded);
    document.getElementById("progress").value = p;            
    document.getElementById("prozent").innerHTML = p + "%";
};

client.onabort = function(e) {
    alert("Upload abgebrochen");
};

client.open("POST", "upload.php");
client.send(formData);
}
```

And my upload.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_FILES['datei']))
{
    //console.log("upload.php!");
     //move_uploaded_file($_FILES['datei']['tmp_name'], 'upload/'.basename($_FILES['datei']['name']));
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES['datei']['tmp_name'], 'upload/hextoflash.hex');
}
else
{
echo "error in $_files";
}
?>
```

and html:

```
    <form name="uploadform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action=""> 
    <br> <input name="uploaddatei" type="file" id="fileA" onchange="fileChange();" /> </br>
    <input name="uploadbutton" value="Hochladen!" style="width: 108px" type="button" onclick="uploadFile();" />
</form>
```

The point is, i already tried to edit php.ini.

1. I checked max_size and so on, its already in the right dimension
2. File was working with an old jquery.js, i updated to jquery2.2.0 because of datatables plugin, so i need that, and since then it seems to not work anymore
3. the rights of the upload folder are 777

So i don't get where the problem is, and if its within jquery, im not able to fix that. is there a method to fix this problem?

Comment: your code seems to be plain javascript so your upload should work

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

It was so easy i would never think of it.
The server drive was simply 100% full.
Deleted some junk and voilá it's running.